# To create a list with multiple list inside it

Tags: c#, json, list, .net-3.5, highcharts

Below is my main list

```
var serie_line = new { name = series_name, data = new List<object>() };
```

here I add items in data as follows,

```
serie_line.data.Add(child_object_name); 
serie_line.data.Add(period_final_value );
```

I then add this var serie_line to another list series as follows,

```
List<object> series = new List<object>(); 
series.Add(serie_line);
```

finally ,I serialize this series into JSON as below,

```
var obj4 = new { legend = legend, title,chart, series};
JSON_File_Returned = jSearializer.Serialize(obj4);
```

whereas

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
```

Now Output I am getting is as follows,

```
 {
    "legend":{"enabled":"true"},
    "title":{"text":"Financial"},
    "chart":{"type":"pie"},
    "series":[
               {"name":"Actual","data":["Market Share",20.00]},
               {"name":"Actual","data":["Sales Growth",30.00]},
               {"name":"Actual","data":["Operating Profit",40.00]},
               {"name":"Actual","data":["Gross Margin %",10.00]}
             ]
  }
```

But my required output is as follows,

```
 {
    "legend":{"enabled":"true"},
    "title":{"text":"Financial"},
    "chart":{"type":"pie"},
    "series":[
               {"name":"Actual","data":[["Market Share",20.00],["Sales Growth",30.00],["Operating Profit",40.00],["Gross Margin %",10.00]]}
             ]
  }
```

So..That I can plot pie chart in highchart using this JSON output...I have tried for everything like using dictionary,making different class and then using it's object and so on...but can't make it out....

Below is my entire code...if in case I am messing with any loop and I don't recognize it but any one might notice it..please check the below code for the same..

```
    var serie_line = new { name = series_name, data = new List<object>() };  

    for (int k = 0; k <= read_Series_Splitted_Name.Length; k++)                                 //for loop for passing chart type in series
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < id_series_before_offset.Count; i++)                                 //for loop for counting series ID
            {
                var xmlAttributeCollection = id_series_before_offset[i].Attributes;
                 if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
                 {
                    var seriesid = xmlAttributeCollection["id"];
                    xmlActions_id[i] = seriesid.Value;
                    resulted_series_id = seriesid.Value;
                    series_name = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, resulted_series_id, "name", "");
                    new_series_name = series_name;
                            series_Atribute = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, resulted_series_id, "symbol", "");
                    if (read_Series_Splitted_Name_store == series_Atribute)
                    {
                       serie_line = new { name = series_name, data = new List<object>() };
                     }

                     k++;
                            //  Forloop for PeriodId and It's Value

                    var value = Read_XML_Before_Offset.SelectNodes("//measure.values/series[" + (i + 1) + "]/value");
                    var xmlActions = new string[value.Count];// for periodname
                    var xmlActionsone = new string[value.Count];  // for period value

                    for (int j = 0; j < value.Count; j++)
                    {

                    var xmlAttributeCollection_for_period = value[j].Attributes;
                     if (xmlAttributeCollection_for_period != null)
                    {

                      if (i == 0 && a == 0)
                      {
                          var periodid = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period["periodid"];
                          xmlActions[j] = periodid.Value;
                          period_final_id = periodid.Value;
                          period_name = Client.GetAttributeAsString(sessionId, periodid.Value, "name", "");
                          period_Name.Add(period_name);
                      }

                      try
                      {
                            var action = xmlAttributeCollection_for_period["value"];  //    xmlActionsone[j] = action.Value;
                            period_final_value = float.Parse(action.Value);
                                            // serie_line.data.Add(period_final_value);
                             serie_line.data.Add(child_object_name);
                             serie_line.data.Add(period_final_value );


                       }
                         catch (Exception ex1)
                       {
                             serie_line.data.Add("");
                             serie_line.data.Add( null );
                       }
                     }
                   }
                }
              }         
            }
           series.Add(serie_line);
```

Comment: if i am not wrong i think you have to use Dictionary Structure instead of List to get required result.

Comment: Nopes...when I used dictionary ..it make use of key: value format...which gives me out put in data as ["Market Share":20.00] after being serialized into JSON...this output doesn't gives pie chart in highcharts

Comment: What do `child_object_name` and `period_final_value` equal?

Comment: Why not make the `name` a separate build statement and then concat the `name` JSON to the `data` JSON and you should get `{name: BLAH, data: [....]}`.

Comment: I did that do...I took name in another list and data in another list and then tried to concatenate it into one list but then I found..it makes name and data different child of same object which worsen the issue..

Comment: @mark... child_object_name=market share and period_final_value=20.00 in first example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C# code should look something like this all stripped down:

```
var serie_line = new { name = "Actual", data = new List<object>() };
serie_line.data.Add(new List<object>() {"Market Share", 20.0});
serie_line.data.Add(new List<object>() {"Sales Growth", 30.0});
serie_line.data.Add(new List<object>() {"Operting Profit", 40.0});
serie_line.data.Add(new List<object>() {"Gross Margin %", 10.0});
jSearializer.Serialize(serie_line);
```

Which produces:

```
    {"name":"Actual","data":[["Market Share",20],["Sales Growth",30],["Operting Profit",40],["Gross Margin %",10]]}
```

I'm not following the bottom part of the code (how you create `child_object_name` and `period_final_value`, but I think you want:

```
    serie_line.data.Add(new List<object>() {child_object_name, period_final_value });
```

Instead of:

```
    serie_line.data.Add(child_object_name);
    serie_line.data.Add(period_final_value );
```

Comment: When I do in this way then it only gives last value in data..please c my below output..{"legend":{"enabled":"true"},"title":{"text":"Financial"},"chart":{"type":"pie"},"serie_line":{"name":"Actual","data":[["Gross Margin %",19.44]]}}

Comment: Sounds like you are recreating `serie_line` inside your loop.  I see you new it up at the beginning of your code block and then inside your highest level loop you `
if (read_Series_Splitted_Name_store == series_Atribute)
                    {
                       serie_line = new { name = series_name, data = new List<object>() };
                     }
`, could this be the source of problems?